# Implementing unit tests for a Python C Extension

Tags: python, python-c-api

So, I have a repo to build a python C extension laid out as follows:

```
setup.py
demo.c
MANIFEST.in
```

The contents of the C file are:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject* print_message(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    const char* str_arg;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &str_arg)) {
        puts("Could not parse the python arg!");
        return NULL;
    }
#ifdef USE_PRINTER
    printf("printer %s\n", str_arg);
#else
    printf("msg %s\n", str_arg);
#endif
    // This can also be done with Py_RETURN_NONE
    Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    return Py_None;
}

static PyMethodDef myMethods[] = {
    { "print_message", print_message, METH_VARARGS, "Prints a called string" },
    { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }
};

// Our Module Definition struct
static struct PyModuleDef myModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "DemoPackage",
    "A demo module for python c extensions",
    -1,
    myMethods
};

// Initializes our module using our above struct
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_DemoPackage(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&myModule);
}
```

In my `setup.py`, I have the following code:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('DemoPackage',
                    define_macros = [('USE_PRINTER', '1')],
                    include_dirs = ['include'],
                    sources = ['src/demo.c'])

setup (name = 'DemoPackage',
       version = '1.0',
       description = 'This is a demo package',
       author = '<first> <last>',
       author_email = 'person@site.com',
       url = 'https://docs.python.org/extending/building',
       long_description = open('README.md').read(),
       ext_modules = [module1])
```

My question here is, if I can build and install the package with the commands:

$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py install

How do I incorporate or write a unit test in the scenario of a C extension? I am looking for the unit test to be run in conjunction with `setup.py`, similarly to how a test would work for cmake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How I've been approaching the problem of unit-testing Python extension module code written in C is to write unit tests in Python for [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/) *but* to then embed the Python interpreter in a separate C test runner which uses [Check](https://libcheck.github.io/check/) to wrap the call to `pytest`. This might seem kinda silly (it does to me honestly), but since C code can leak memory and cause all sorts of nasty signals to be raised, using a Check runner runs everything in a separate address space so the test runner can catch any signals and (hopefully) say something meaningful about them instead of me just seeing the Python interpreter crash. I would say the way to go about unit testing C extension code is to build the extension *inplace*, i.e. using `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace` which will put the shared object (I'm on Linux) in the same directory as your `demo.c` file (or source folder), and then you can use whatever you would like for unit testing. I personally use `make` and the build target for my test runner depends on the C extension being successfully built inplace.

It's unfortunate that no one has yet answered this question; I was actually hoping someone would have a better method of tackling this exact problem. If you're interested in doing something similar, here's sample code for a Check test runner and relevant `Makefile` recipe to build the runner.

```c
/* check/pytest_suite.h */

#ifndef PYTEST_SUITE_H
#define PYTEST_SUITE_H

#include <check.h>

Suite *pytest_suite();

#endif /* PYTEST_SUITE_H */
```

```c
/* check/pytest_suite.c */

#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include "Python.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <check.h>
#include "pytest_suite.h"

START_TEST(print_stuff)
{
  // initialize interpreter, load pytest main and run (relies on pytest.ini)
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from pytest import main\nmain()\n");
  // required finalization function; if something went wrong, exit immediately
  if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
    // __func__ only defined in C99+
    fprintf(stderr, "error: %s: Py_FinalizeEx error\n", __func__);
    exit(120);
  }
}
END_TEST

Suite *pytest_suite() {
  // create suite called pytest_suite + add test case named core
  Suite *suite = suite_create("pytest_suite");
  TCase *tc_core = tcase_create("core");
  // register case together with test func, add to suite, and return suite
  tcase_add_test(tc_core, print_stuff);
  suite_add_tcase(suite, tc_core);
  return suite;
}
```

```c
/* check/runner.c */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <check.h>

#include "pytest_suite.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  // instantiate our test suite. note this does not have to be freed!
  Suite *suite = pytest_suite();
  // create our suite runner and run all tests (CK_ENV -> set CK_VERBOSITY and
  // if not set, default to CK_NORMAL, i.e. only show failed)
  SRunner *runner = srunner_create(suite);
  srunner_run_all(runner, CK_ENV);
  // get number of failed tests and free runner
  int n_failed = srunner_ntests_failed(runner);
  srunner_free(runner);
  // succeed/fail depending on value of number of failed cases
  return (n_failed == 0) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

```
# Makefile (GNU make)

CC             = gcc
PYTHON        ?= python3
# dependencies for test running code
CHECK_DEPS     = $(wildcard check/*.c)
# use python3-config to get python compiler and linker flags for use when
# linking python into external C code (our test runner)
PY_CFLAGS     ?= -fPIE $(shell python3-config --cflags)
# --embed is required on ubuntu or -lpythonx.y is omitted by --ldflags
PY_LDFLAGS    ?= $(shell python3-config --embed --ldflags)
# linker flags specifically for compiling the test runner (libcheck)
CHECK_LDFLAGS  = $(PY_LDFLAGS) -lcheck

# build C extension module inplace. change dependencies as needed.
inplace: demo.c
    @$(PYTHON) setup.py build_ext --inplace

# build test runner and run unit tests using check
check: $(CHECK_DEPS) inplace
    @$(CC) $(PY_CFLAGS) -o runner $(CHECK_DEPS) $(CHECK_LDFLAGS)
    @./runner
```

Of course, for this to work, you'll need to have Check and GNU Make installed on your system. I'm using WSL Ubuntu 18.04; `make` came with the distribution and I built Check from scratch using their [latest release](https://github.com/libcheck/check/releases/tag/0.15.2). Using this setup, when I execute `make check`, `make inplace` gets called whenever `demo.c` is updated or `touch`ed, and my test runner is built and run.

Hope this at least gives you some new ideas.